# Dilemma of whether to say "à sa hauteur" or "à leur hauteur"

Tags: pluriel

> Je ne peux pas jouer **les mégères** qui ne trouvent pas de rival à **leur** hauteur !

If you strictly abide by grammatical number agreement, "leur" should be chosen. But the use of "leur" jumps out at me.

After all, the plural noun "mégères" does not refer to actual multiple people, but rather it is more about the same single person playing the role of several different "mégères", each ever so slightly nuanced, if you will.

So the temptation is great to use the singular "sa", the more logic-driven alternative:

> Je ne peux pas jouer **les mégères** qui ne trouvent pas de rival à **sa** hauteur !

The only snag is that "sa" cannot help but jar with the plural "mégères", so I'm now tempted to change "mégères" into the singular:

> Je ne peux pas jouer **la mégère** qui ne trouve pas de rival à **sa** hauteur !

The issue of the plural-singular mismatch has now been resolved, but herein lies another problem: In the idiomatic expression "jouer les + plural noun", I'm not sure if it is acceptable to use the singular form.

All in all, which is the most idiomatic way to express this idea?

Comment: Pourquoi pas « …jouer les mégères qui ne trouvent pas de rivaux à leurs hauteurs » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je crois que dans les faits, il y une certaine variation entre le singulier et le pluriel. Après tout, au sens de "interpréter un rôle" (*Je joue la servante dans cette pièce.*), duquel cette expression est directement dérivée, le verbe prend très bien un complément singulier. Donc, autant le pluriel que le singulier est valide après *jouer* puisque de toute façon le sens très exact du mot dans cette phrase n'est pas vraiment déterminable.

Il est clair qu'on ne peut pas justifier un pronom singulier avec un référent pluriel ici. Ça ne passe tout simplement pas. Je suis d'accord que la troisième version est un peu plus idiomatique, mais la première est grammaticalement tout aussi impeccable.

Comment: Merci. Ce qui me chiffonne, c'est que je constate qu’un nom dans la locution « jouer + noun » au sens figuré telle que « jouer les durs » ne s’emploie au singulier que très rarement. D'où mon inquiétude là-dessus.

Answer (score 2):

From a purely academic grammatical point of view, it should be :

> à **leur** hauteur !

This is a very simple rule of grammar who does not care about the context of the sentence. From the same perspective, if you wanted to say

> Of all bats, Batman is the best !

You would say :

> De toutes les chauves-souris, Batman est la meilleure !

Eventhough we know Batman is a male, we still use the feminine form, as we refer to a bat, which is feminine in french. The same rule applies here.

As for your question, the most idiomatic and natural way to express it would be :

> Je ne peux pas jouer la mégère qui ne trouve pas de rival à sa hauteur !

It is not incorrect ; actually, both of your propositions are correct, but the singular version feels more natural for a native speaker, as they will be referring to themselves.

Comment: L'exemple de batman est grammaticalement correct, bien que faux parce que Batman n'est *pas* une chauve souris. C'est un peu comme dire "de toutes les citrouilles, mon appartement est le meilleur". Grammaticalement correct...

Comment: Oui, en effet, j'ai voulu utiliser un exemple que je connaissais et qui était assez parlant (accorder le descriptif d'un homme au féminin). Ce qui est visé est bien entendu la règle grammaticale.