# Singular or plural: "les 1 femme japonaise sur 3 qui est/sont effrayée(s)"

Tags: accord, pluriel, nombres

In conversation with my friends, I wasn't sure if I should construct the following sentence in  the singular or plural:

> Si tu fais partie des 1 femme japonaise sur 3 qui **est** effrayée à l'idée de vivre une grossesse pour la première fois, rassure-toi car ...
>
> Si tu fais partie des 1 femme japonaise sur 3 qui **sont** effrayées à l'idée de vivre une grossesse pour la première fois, rassure-toi car ...

This might qualify as a rather unique instance where you cannot make a clear-cut choice between the singular and plural. Incidentally, even in English, "1 out of 3 Japanese women **is**/**are**" is a controversial topic.

Interpretation 1:

> "**les** 1 femme japonaise sur 3" = "**33%** of Japanese women" = plural = "qui **sont** effrayées"

Interpretation 2:

> "les **1 femme** japonaise sur 3" = "**one** out of three Japanese women" = singular = "qui **est** effrayée"

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2770/10519

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important detail here is the *les* article. It clearly indicates that you're treating the phrase *1 femme japonaise sur 3* as a plural and it's impossible once you've used that article to put the verb in the singular (to allow either options, it would have to be phrased *le tiers des femmes japonaises*).

It's the exact same phenomenon as in [your other recent question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26657) about plural versus singular. Pretty much the only time that a nominal group with *les* may allow a singular agreement is when some sort of proper noun is involved (i.e. work titles, band names, families... because in those cases the article is pretty much part of the proper noun instead of an agreement marker). The reverse (singular noun referring to a group with a plural agreement) is more likely to occur, hence the remark about wording this with *le tiers*.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Depuis de nombreux mois déjà cette question m’a occasionnellement trotté par la tête, et maintenant seulement je cerne des formulations qui me conviennent suffisamment pour en parler.</sub>

---

Je suis parti du principe que ***faire partie de***, en ce cas mais aussi en tous ceux auxquels j’ai pu penser, implique la possibilité d’appliquer le verbe ***être*** au sujet.

De cette circonstance, il devient possible d’identifier directement l’interlocutrice à cette femme sur trois, auquel cas on privilégiera le singulier qui s’impose de soi :

- Si tu es cette femme japonaise sur trois **effrayée** à l’idée de vivre une première grossesse, rassure-toi car...

On pourra aussi éviter l’identification directe, pour amortir l’idée un peu sèche de classification :

- Si tu t’identifies à cette japonaise sur trois qui **est effrayée** à l’idée de vivre une première grossesse, rassure-toi car...

Dans le cas d’une proportion plus complexe, un simple ajustement suffirait, et le choix du nombre, pluriel ici, sera aussi naturel que l’élection du singulier des exemples précédents :

- Si tu es l’une de ces trois femmes japonaises sur cinq qui **préfèrent** la canelle à la vanille, tu béniras ce jour qui voit l’arrivée de la chaîne *Cinnamon Buns Illimited* sur le territoire japonais.

Dans le cas de pourcentages, la formulation est plus simple :

- Si, comme 35% des femmes japonaises, **tu appréhendes** ta première grossesse au point de ne plus pouvoir te concentrer sur autre chose, rassure-toi car...

Quant aux proportions exprimées en fractions, le choix est plus difficile. J’opterais personnellement pour le féminin pluriel, car il s’agit de nombreuses femmes et que ça évite de divertir l’attention en usant pour elles du masculin *(ce serait encore plus marquant dans le cas d’un terme variant au féminin, comme petite, gentille ou autre)*, mais d’autres pourraient argumenter autrement, puisque *« tiers »* ici est un collectif, pour lequel l’accord peut varier selon le rattachement de l’action ou état décrit au collectif ou aux individus particuliers composant le collectif, rattachement qui sera parfois assez clair, parfois plus flou et à la discrétion de la personne s’exprimant. On pourra consulter à ce propos bien des sources (par exemple la [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1443)).

- Si tu es de *ce tiers* <sub>***masculin singulier***</sub> des *femmes japonaises* <sub>***féminin pluriel***</sub> qui **sont effrayées** d’une première grossesse, rassure-toi car...

Mais comme l’indique [aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17526) ci-dessous, l’option demeure de contourner le problème en insérant le comparatif **comme**, de la même manière que pour l’exemple des pourcentages :

- Si, comme un tiers des femmes japonaises, **tu es effrayée** à l’idée de vivre une première grossesse, rassure-toi car...

---

Si ***faire partie de*** devait être conservé coûte que coûte, la structure est lourde et je ne la recommanderais pas particulièrement mais sait-on jamais ?, on peut placer la proportion en incise, où son singulier, isolé, ne causera pas d’ambiguïté avec le pluriel des femmes :

- Si tu fais partie de ces femmes japonaises, une sur trois, **effrayées** de vivre une première grossesse, rassure-toi car...

L’exemple qui précède souffre cependant de deux tares :

- À l’oral, l’utilisation d’incises tue le plus souvent l’impression de spontanéité et laisse à croire que l’on récite un texte standardisé.
- À l’écrit, le message n’est pas personnel et le tutoiement risque d’être mal reçu.

Pour y remédier à l’oral, on peut casser la structure et réassembler, par exemple :

- Savais-tu qu’une japonaise sur trois **est effrayée** de vivre une première grossesse ? (Si tu fais partie / Si tu es) de celles-là, rassure-toi car...

À l’écrit, le passage au vouvoiement résoudra facilement le problème :

- Si vous faites partie de ces femmes japonaises, une sur trois, **effrayées** de vivre une première grossesse, rassurez-vous car...

Comment: 35%... j'aurais dit moins approximativement... *un tiers*. ;-)

Comment: Oui bon! On peut toujours approximer en ce cas particulier. Si par contre en un autre contexte des recherches tendent à démontrer qu’il s’agit bien de disons 34% plutôt que du tiers exact qui était pressenti, ou accepté jusqu’alors, il est bon d’être exact. Circonstances, contexte et nature de la statistique invoquée peuvent faire varier le choix de la présentation du nombre, mais ça dépasse largement le cadre de la question...

Comment: @aCOSwt En vérité je vous le dis, je me dois de vous remercier d’avoir remué la marmite. En dépit de mon objection ci-dessus, valide je crois, j'ai finalement compris ce que vous sous-entendiez à demi-mot.

Comment: Thanks++. Que vous comprendriez le demi-mot... je m'en doutais... c'est ça que je trouve agréable avec vous! Vous m'évitez les 1000 lignes de commentaires... que... l'on me reproche par ailleurs... Merci... mille fois!

Comment: Notez bien que vous pouviez très bien reprendre votre précédente formulation à l'identique : *"si comme 35% des..."* -> *"si comme un tiers des..."*. Il n'y a alors plus de problème de choix.

Answer (score 2):

Circeus is correct, but anyway you should not say "les une femmes sur trois",
because with "une" you must have the singular.
So you can say "si, comme une japonaise sur trois, tu es effrayée...".

Comment: That's a fair point. "Les une" is technically grammatical, but rather awkward.

Answer (score 1):

L'important ici est le "les" utilisé qui suggère un pluriel. Donc ta première interprétation est la bonne.

Quand tu dis

> Si tu fais partie **des une femme sur trois** qui **sont** brunes

tu sous-entend

> si tu fais partie **des femmes** brunes parmi toutes les femmes tu as donc un pluriel.

Par contre on dit :

> **une femme** sur trois **est** grande

car on ne fait pas référence à plusieurs femmes mais bien à une seule sur les trois c'est un statistique pure et dure et non une référence à plusieurs personnes.